# WebClient UseDefaultCredentials doesn't work for ldap authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory, webclient

I have webforms asp.net website that uses AD authentication,  I am using webclient to post to a url.  Everything works fine when I use NetworkCredentials, but fails with UseDefaultCredentials.

Works: `myWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("uname", "pwd");`

Doesn't work: `myWebClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;`

Both lines of code work locally on my machine when runniing from Visual Studio, which uses IIS Express.  But when deployed to my server, I get "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." error for the UseDefaultCredentials scenario.  I would prefer to use UseDefaultCredentials as I am using AD authentication and users password is not available at runtime.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever tried

```
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

I saw people talked about it before. Hope it works for u.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.